# I want to learn how to use populate() and aggregate()

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, aggregate, populate

For the past couple of months i've been learning how to code through looking at videos following along reading documentations and generally fiddling around.

I've been stuck countless amount of times trying to understand one simple thing after another, until I got fairly adapt at solving my own problems through quick google searches, recollection and repeating the same task.

But what i found the most beneficial to my learning was looking at other people's code and then trying to understand how it works, more specifically whenever there is a function i dont understand i look at a application online and see how the function is used and what the end result is the problem is I can't seem to find a fitting application for learning how to use populate() and aggregate().

I'l be honest, I never learned very well through just reading something and then understanding it, I only ever learn well when I myself am actively doing it and seeing the results for myself.

This is why i am asking you all in this wonder community if you know a application that actively uses populate() or aggregate() or makes it the main focus.

What i want to understand is how to use these two functions and when to use them, because while I understand their concept and what they are used for, in practice I just can't seem to understand at all.

Furthermore I am confused on where they are exactly used as well, I've only dabbled in react, mongoose and other generally associated npms to do with website making.

Please help.